# intel media software encoder

Tags: windows-8, intel, video-encoding, intel-media-sdk

I am using **graph edit**, and trying to use **intel media software encoder** with windows-8 (32-bit, Processor Intel-core i5) and getting configuration error

But it works fine with following situation :

- Windows-8 (64 bit , Processor intel-core i3),
- Windows-7 (32 bit , Processor intel-core i3),
- Windows-7 (64 bit , Processor intel-core i3).

Please help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: which encoder were you using? and did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Which version of the Media SDK are you using?  Did you initialize the SDK session by specifying the API version?  For example:
mfxVersion ver = {3, 1};
MFXInit(MFX_IMPL_AUTO, ver, session);  The link to the SDK page is here:  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/video-conferencing-features-of-intel-media-software-development-kit   Did you take a look at the "sample_videoconf"?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in Compatibility mode and make sure the installed version is 32bit and run it in admin mode, if it doesn't help.Post a few Screenshots for people to understand the issue.